Is there a way to send a 'reaction' emoji to an email in an outlook email account from thunderbird / programmatically?
When using outlook (e.g. the web interface), you have the option of adding a 'reaction' to an email, consisting of a limited set of emojis, as seen in the picture below:

The most typical use for this is a 'thumbs up' reaction, effectively acting as some sort of acknowledgement of having read the email, without having to make an explicit email reply to point this out.
I use thunderbird, but find that on occasion, a reaction is really the most appropriate response to an email, and I can't do that on thunderbird, which means I have to load up outlook on the browser just for the reaction bit.
My question is
a) Is there an existing way of doing this in thunderbird (e.g. via an addon)
b) If not, is anyone aware of an API that could be used to create such an addon, to 'send' reactions from thunderbird (or programmatically in the more general sense).

When both the sender and the recipient are in O365, Outlook uses an internal API (the last time I checked). While Teams has API for that (setReaction), I don't think there is currently API to set reactions for emails.
If the mailboxes are not in O365, Outlook just sends a regular message
<user name> reacted to your message:


In other words, standard email clients like Thunderbird typically don't have access to this API, though in principle, you could perhaps write a plug-in which enables this (if it's a documented API, and not quite as borken as many of these Microsoft offerings).

All the latest MS APIs use OAuth, whcih means you'd need to register your app on the per-tenant basis (yuck) to be able to prompt the user for credentials and get access/refresh tokens.
